# Spring MVC ajax call a controller using

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadFIReport.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String downloadFIBill(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") FIReportSearchInput fiReportSearchInput)
{

//

}
```

Above is my controller code. I want to send `FIReportSearchInput fiReportSearchInput` as input without binding it to page using a `<form:form/>` tag and using jQuery's Ajax method

```
$.ajax()
```

How can this be done ?

Update here is the definition of FIReportSearchInput

```
public class FIReportSearchInput {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date startDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date endDate;

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }



}
```

Comment: Is this FIReportSearchInput object not coming from the view(JSP)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example,you can try it:
I suppose FIReportSearchInput have id and name attributes.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"downloadFIReport.do",
  type:"post",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{id:$("#id").val(),name:$("#name").val()},
  success:function(){}
});
```

when the spring mvc server catch this request,if your answer body is 'FIReportSearchInput fiReportSearchInput' and Object FIReportSearchInput have id and name attributes,it will call setter method automatically to build a new FIReportSearchInput Object named fiReportSearchInput.

Comment: Both the fields are date type. can they be handled too ?

Comment: You'd better convert date to string,cause the format could be different between javascript and java.